# How to find out how many slices of pizza I need

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

This seems like such a simple problem but I am stuck.

I have 50 different pizzas. There are 30 humans that have to share them.

I want that each person eats from 6 different pizzas. We can have two different persons eating from the same pizza, but each individual has to eat from 6 different pizzas.

Also each pizza has to be proved, else the solution would be to cut 6 pizzas in 30 pieces and ignoring the rest.

How many slices do I need to cut the pizzas, at the minimun?

First I thought about doing this with combinations and permutations but I am doing something wrong. Is this a minimization problem? Part of the problem for me is it has been a long while since I tried to solve this kind of problems, and I am having trouble finding the "context" or branch of mathematics I should use.

I am sorry if this is not the right place/way to ask.

Comment: First thought: If you have 30 people and each eats from 6 different pizzas (that is, 6 slices per person), you must have at least $6\times 30 = 180$ pizza slices.

Comment: With "each pizza has to be proved", do you mean that for each pizza, at least one person has to take a slice of it?

Comment: yes exactly @MattiP. And the 180 is as far as I have got so far!

Comment: Does the distribution of slices alter the total number of slices at all? Consider you have four people and two pizzas. You can split the pizzas into $2+2$ slices or $3+1$ slices. Are you considering only the number of slices (portions) or the number of actual cuts you have to make to the pizzas? In this example, $2+2$ would mean one cut per pizza (two cuts in total) and $3+1$ means three cuts (if you don't want any leftovers) or two cuts (one piece will be left over) plus zero cuts. You get what I'm saying?

Comment: @MattiP. I am not 100% sure I follow but as of right now I do not care if there are leftovers, as far as everyone eats 6. I know it makes sense to make the problem smaller but part of the difficulty for me is the restrictions: everyone has to eat from 6 different ones, and all pizzas have to be eaten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the pizzas as an excel-sheet with 50 columns. Now in the first row start entering the first name, for six columns, then the next name, for the next six columns... 8x6=48, so you'll be able to fit eight names in the first row, with two pizzas not yet sampled.

As Matti P. said, 6 x 30 = 180 pizza-slices (or in our case excel-cells) need to be named. Three rows will get you 150 cells, four rows 200 cells, so depending on whether you have to cut all pizzas the same, you'll either have to cut them all into 4 pieces, or 30 into four pieces and 20 into three.

No cell (=piece) can be occupied by more than one name, because every tester eats one whole piece, therefore you need at least (Number_of_testers x number_of_samples) 180 servings. The minimal cutting depends on the rules for cutting (pizzas individually (30@4p 20@3), or stack the pizzas and cut all at once (50@4p, with some uneaten pieces).

Comment: Thanks for the help!!     That is a great way of looking at the problem but I feel like there is no guarantee that is the minimum, unless I am wrong? I mean, it is a solution but I do not see a way to go from there to conclude: this is the minimum.

Comment: Tried to put more emphasis on it being minimal.